# Bucket uploaded file not shown in all mounted VMs

Tags: gcloud, gsutil, gcsfuse, fstab

I have a Google Cloud Storage Bucket which is mounted to 3 virtual machines using fstab.

When I upload a file from another machine to google bucket using gsutil command, the uploaded file is accessible from only 2 vms (**Set A**). The other vm (**Set B**) doens't show the newly uploaded file.

***fstab*** entry used for mounting is as follows.

```
bucket_name mounted_path gcsfuse rw,uid=1002,gid=1003,user,allow_other,key_file=key_file_path
```

Content of */etc/mtab* file from **Set A** is as follows.

```
bucket_name mounted_path fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1002,group_id=1003,default_permissions 0 0
```

Content of */etc/mtab* file from **Set B** is as follows.

```
bucket_name mounted_path fuse fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do mounting Storage Buckets on VMs:

- create a VM instance and give it Storage "full" access scope. if you
  have already a VM, edit that VM with this scope. note that you need
  to stop the VM to edit it's access scope.
- install gcsfuse on your instance if you haven't already
- create a directory on where you want to mount your bucket `mkdir /path/to/bucket`
- go to Cloud Storage and edit your bucket permissions by adding the compute engine default service account as a **Storage Admin**, you can find this service account in **IAM&admin --> service account**, it has this structure **1213242443-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com**
- use `gcsfuse bucket_name /path/to/bucket` to mount your bucket. here gcsfuse will use the default service account to verify access and make the connection. this is the easiest way as it conclude few steps
- now any file you upload to your bucket will appear in VMs bucket mounting folder `/path/to/bucket`

[Read more about this process here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse)